# wordpress Fatal error: Allowed memory size (weird)

Tags: php, wordpress, wampserver

Today when I tried to edit my site on local I got strange error like this :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 6874029536211531203 bytes) in
>   D:\wamp64ario\www\owjgraph\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5231

Why it tried to allocate for 6874029536211531203?

Sometimes I get this when I try to reach Login Page, other times in different situations like dashboard or update posts etc.

I tried many things but no success:

1. My other website in local (with no plugins or various plugins) get the same error.
2. Increased `memory_limit` to 256, 512 or 1GB in WAMP but no success.
3. I heard version 4.9.7 have some memory leak bug so I downgraded to older versions and problem still exists.
4. Uninstall and reinstall WAMP.
5. Install other local tools like MAMP.
6. Clear cache and cookies and use different browser
7. Install fresh WordPress 4.9.7, 4.9.5 and 4.9.1

None of them solved my problem and I'm really confused.

Is this something wrong with my Windows or registry? How can I debug or trace where this problem is coming from?

Comment: Although sometimes the solution for a _maximum memory size exhausted_ error can be to increase the max memory, more often than not the real problem is that there's something wrong with your code. That is: you're actually allocating more memory than you should. In your case this happens on this line: `D:\wamp64ario\www\owjgraph\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5231`. Can you share that line and the relevant code around it? That would probably be the function that that line is part of.

Comment: here is 5231 line code : function wp_is_stream( $path ) {
 $wrappers = stream_get_wrappers();
 $wrappers_re = '(' . join('|', $wrappers) . ')';

Answer (score 0):

Try: Look in your error logs, you may get a trace that will zero in on the problem for you (like an infinite loop).

Locate the line that is throwing the error & determine if it can be refactored to avoid the memory usage.

You can override php's memory allocation in your wp-config, like so:
`define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );` but this is just a bandaid in my opinion. There is likely something wrong, which you'll need to fix for the long term health of your application.

Comment: `6874029536211531203 bytes` won't be possible with a memory limit setting, unless this server has a hugeee amount of RAM.

Comment: define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' ); not help .

Comment: @user3783243 "unless this server has a hugeee amount of RAM" 6 Exabyte to be exact in this case.

Comment: @sanazrahimi start with Wordpress error log, I am not familiar with WAMP error reporting, but I'd look at any php error logs available to you.

Comment: @user3783243 - good point, there's definitely some kind of major memory link happening. Won't reach that kind of allocation by upping php's limit, nor should you.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening to me. If I var_dump stream_get_wrappers() I get weird results with very long lines of gibberish text. I think it's WAMP's fault, because I also get this error in plain php.
Temporary solution for WordPress:

Open wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php and modify wp_is_stream function to look like this:

```
function wp_is_stream( $path ) {
    $wrappers = stream_get_wrappers();

    for ($i=0;$i<count($wrappers);$i++) {

        if (strlen($wrappers[$i])>100) {
            unset($wrappers[$i]);
        }
    }

    $wrappers_re = '(' . join('|', $wrappers) . ')';

    return preg_match( "!^$wrappers_re://!", $path ) === 1;
}
```

I use WampServer 3.0.6 64bit

Comment: I dont think you can blame WAMPServer for WordPress trying to allocate 6 Exabyte of memory. This is why PHP has a memory limit, so these coding issues dont blow the whole server out of the water

Comment: It is most likely WAMP's fault. The problem is in php builtin function stream_get_wrappers() which returns abnormal results under WAMP server.

Comment: This is a bad idea - next WP update - this file will most likely be reset, it's a plaster not a fix. Also, it's not WAMP specific as I get this too on my Linux machine occasionally